# How are client charset and server charset related?

Tags: utf-8, sap-ase, iso-8859-1

My client is Aqua Data studio.

I am connecting to SAP ASE 16.0 with the default charset. I assume it is ISO 8859-1, same as the DB server charset.

I tried to insert the Euro symbol into a table, which understandably didn't work because ISO 8859-1 does not support it.

Just for testing purpose, I created a new connection in ADS with UTF-8 encoding. I inserted the Euro symbol again but in a Unitext column, which worked.

Selecting from that table gives the Euro symbol in a connection using UTF-8 charset.

But it works perfectly fine with the default charset too. I mean I am able to see Euro symbols when I do `Select *` from that table.

I was expecting a connection with ISO 8859-1 encoding to show `?`.

Can anyone please explain how the translation works?

Comment: Maybe it's Windows CP-1252, which is based on ISO 8859-1, but includes the € symbol.

Comment: @lenz it's definitely ISO 8859-1 ([Link](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc35823.1600/doc/html/san1334282791298.html))